# Wearing a Kittel at the Seder

Tags: minhag, passover, clothing, passover-seder-hagada, kittel

I grew up with my father wearing a Kittel at the Seder. My father wore a Kittel at the Seder immediately from when he got married. Over the years I have heard that some people do not wear a Kittel the first year, and in some instances only the one leading the Seder wears a Kittel. Who wears? Starting when? When not? Why? (sources please)

Comment: An extensive educational and entertaining treatment on this topic [Here](http://havolim.blogspot.com/search/label/Kittel)

Comment: what is a Kittel ?

Comment: A Kittel is a completely white garment that some people wear on Pesach at the Seder. It is also worn by some on Yom Kippur for Davening. In addition people get buried in it.

Comment: People get buried in white garments, not a Kittel.

Comment: Many people get buried in their Kittel - see link - http://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/207/Q6/

Comment: @Avraham a Kittel (Yid: קיטל), which means "little robe" in Yiddish is the traditional Ashkenazi white robe which is generally worn at Jewish funerals and burials, as well as Yom Kippur, and more popularly the Pesach seder. It is symbolic of angelic white robes. On Yom Kippur, married men wear a kittel to symbolize that we must be as pure as the color white is associated with pureness. (BTW, only married men wear a kittel, and also, I don't know of a Sepharadi equivalent.)

Comment: Many Ashkenazic grooms wear a kittel under the chuppa when they get married.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Netziv, in the introduction to his commentary on the Hagadah, *Imrei Shefer*, notes that some say the reason for the kittel is to remind one of death, and we shouldn't be **too** happy on seder night. He rejects this reason out-of-hand.

He suggests instead that we're recreating the experience of eating the Passover offering, and has sources to indicate that people would wear fine Egyptian linen clothes for special occasions like that.

While it's purely conjecture, you could suggest that according to reason #1, maybe your first year of marriage should be super-duper happy (so no kittel); according to the Netziv's reason, there should be no difference between your first married year and others. But it's a source.

Comment: Not having a copy of the הגדה in question, I was taught in the name of that same נצי"ב that it was specifically the one bringing the קרבן (one per חבורה) who would wear special clothing and therefore only the "leader" (or exactly one other person perhaps) wears one in modern times as well.

Comment: Could be; I don't recall his exact wording. But you could derive various forms of the custom from his reasoning.

Answer (score 8):

(Sort of a repeat of part of [R'Shalom's answer](/q/6527), but with a source for his conjecture, so I'll just answer separately.) [*Taame Haminhagim* 503](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&st=&pgnum=235) says the reason one wears a *kitl* is to keep him somber by reminding him of death; he adds that because of the a mourner wears it, but a bridegroom (in his first year after marriage) does not (as he should be happy).

Answer (score 5):

My family,as well as many others in *Klal Yisrael*, (see Haggadas Arzei Levanon) (also Chasidei Gur) does not have the custom of wearing a *kittel* at the *seder*.

Comment: My father. His father. His father etc. Look in Arzei Levanon you will find Gedolim who did not wear it. Also my understanding is that Chasidei Gur do not wear a kittel by the seder.

Comment: Nor do Lubavitcher chassidim.

Comment: Alex, that would explain my family's minhag, given my Kaposter background!

Comment: Nor does my family. We are of German descent (yekke).

Answer (score 4):

[R' Herschel Schachter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hershel_Schachter) discusses this in [his Haggadah](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1680251058)*:

[image]
[image]

*R' Schachter's Haggadah is compiled by Reb Allan Weissman