# Wearing the Kittel

Tags: clothing, kittel

Is street clothing under a kittel when you wear one on Yom Kippur and Rosh Hashanah? What is the situation on Pesach? I have not found the answer anywhere on the net.

Comment: Some people wear a jacket, shirt and trousers etc under their kittel; some do not wear a jacket. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: Why do you think there would be any rule about this? Maybe people wear Hawaiin shirts? Maybe they wear nothing at all? Who cares?

Comment: Why would wearing a kittel change any other requirement of wearing clothing for the holiday? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27147/bigdei-shabbos-on-erev-pesach

Comment: Gramattical phrasing, I think. Are you asking if one is allowed to wear street clothing under the kittel on Yom Kippur, Rosh Hashannah  or Pesach? Why do you think that they wouldn't be? Are you talking about walking outside wearing the kittel on these days? What do you mean by "street" clothes?

Comment: My question is very simple: does one wear street clothes under the white kittle on Yom Kippur and Rosh Hasanah? Wearing a kittle is new to me. I recently found out thst it is a minhag for me, but I can not ask my family as I am the only descendant left from my Grandfather, The reason I ask is because my new white kittle appears to be too small to wear a shirt under it. OBVIOUSLY one would wear pstrat pants under the kittle.

Comment: @Oldwolfgilwell Do you have any reason to think it matters what you wear underneath? If not then why are you asking? If yes, please [edit] it in. Until then, this question seems silly.

Comment: I learnt (source unknown) that for the Seder you should be dressed as if ready to go outside on a journey - i.e. outdoor shoes and "properly" dressed. How you define "properly" is a personal matter.

Comment: Thank you Avrohom Yitzchok that exactly answers my question. I appreciate your response.

Comment: I would wear a white kittel on Pesach because my Grandfather did it before me. Thank you for asking Dude.

Comment: @Dude https://www.kof-k.org/articles/040108100429W-24%20Pesach%20-%20The%20Kittel%20Four%20Cups%20and%20Afikomen.pdf and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6524/wearing-a-kittel-at-the-seder discuss the minhag of wearing a kittel at the seder.

Comment: My custom has been to take off my suit jacket before putting on the kittel and put the jacket back on when taking the kittel off. On Rosh Hashannah and Yom Kippur, I leave the kittel at my seat in shul so the regular rules of dress would apply when going to shul or going home.